# Control has no parent window

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I've checked out many threads of a similar title but they haven't helped.

The following compiles and installs to the component palette, but when I try to add the component to a panel, I get the error message mentioned in the thread title.

Could anyone please explain why?

```cpp
__fastcall TEditBox::TEditBox(TComponent* Owner) : TGroupBox(Owner)
{
    ToolBar=new TToolBar(this);
    ToolBar->Parent=this;
    TToolButton *Btn=new TToolButton(ToolBar);
    Btn->Parent=ToolBar;
}
```

If I omit the `Btn->Parent=ToolBar` line, everything's OK, so presumably that's the problem line?

Comment: Don't think you need to assign parent for a tool button. Doesn't the toolbar do that.

Comment: Tried it David but then no button shows. Only way I could get the button to show was to assign the Btn->Parent after the constructor had executed.

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316113/control-has-no-parent-window-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Control '' has no parent window" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316113/control-has-no-parent-window-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a ToolButton's `Parent` requires the ToolBar to have an allocated HWND, which requires it to have a `Parent` with an allocated `HWND`, and so on. But your EditBox does not have a `Parent` (or a `Name`) assigned yet when its constructor is called, so the ToolBar cannot allocate an `HWND` yet, hence the error.

If you want your Toolbar to have a default button at runtime, you need to move the creation of the button to the EditBox's virtual `Loaded()` method (or even the `SetParent()` method), eg:

```cpp
__fastcall TEditBox::TEditBox(TComponent* Owner)
    : TGroupBox(Owner)
{
    ToolBar=new TToolBar(this);
    ToolBar->Parent=this;
}

void __fastcall TEditBox::Loaded()
{
    TGroupBox::Loaded();
    TToolButton *Btn=new TToolButton(ToolBar);
    Btn->Parent=ToolBar;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I went the SetParent route so the buttons (real code had several) were showing at design time.